# Can you convert this to an embed? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

This code works, I just want it to be converted to an embed:

```py
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def dm(self, ctx, user_id: int, *, message: str):
        """ DM the user of your choice """
        await ctx.message.delete()
        user = self.bot.get_user(user_id)
        if not user:
            return await ctx.send(f"Could not find any UserID matching **{user_id}**")

        try:
           await user.send(message + f"\nMessage Sent By <@{ctx.author.id}>\n{ctx.author.name}{ctx.author.discriminator}")
           await ctx.send(f"✉️ Sent a DM to {user.name + '#' + user.discriminator}")
        except discord.Forbidden:
            await ctx.send("This user might be having DMs blocked or it's a bot account...")
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Have you tried to convert the code on your own? can you share an example of your attempts? what issues did you run into? questions with these details will be received better. simply stating "i dont know how to do this, can you do it for me" can be received as a sign that you have put little to no effort in trying to find a solution yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an embed, use [`discord.Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed):

```py
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def dm(self, ctx, user_id: int = None, *, message: str = None):
        """DMs the user of your choice."""
        try:
            await ctx.message.delete()
        except: # If it fails to delete the invocation message
            pass

        user = self.bot.get_user(user_id)
        if not user:
            await ctx.send(f"Could not find any UserID matching **{user_id}**")
            return

        embed = discord.Embed(title="New message", description=message)
        embed.set_footer(text="Message Sent By " + str(ctx.author), icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    
        try:
            await user.send(embed=embed)
            await ctx.send("✉️ Sent a DM to " + str(user))
        except discord.Forbidden:
            await ctx.send("This user might be having DMs blocked or it's a bot account...")
```

Comment: bot.command is not what im using, I have cogs, what i posted was fine, it seems what i sent was edited and my question was completely thrown out of the window, what i was asking before was if someone could convert it to an embed, the code works just fine, i just want it into an embed.

Comment: it errors, "Extension 'cogs.admin' raised an error: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"
Its fine, I know how to embed now, thanks anyway.

Comment: There was just some indent issues, it seems to be fixed. 
Just tested it, it works fine, i apologize for getting a little heated, thank you for the help